# Incorrect spatial extent for imported HDF image on ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, georeferencing, imagery

I imported an hdf image onto ArcGIS but I cannot make correct projection of it. Also, it does not have correct spatial extent (please see the enclosed figure, the small one is projected under WGS84). I try to define the projection of the hdf raster but the tool just simply doesn't run. The hdf raster has 7200 columns and 3600 rows while the small one has 3600 columns and 1800 rows.

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Jakub's right ..... just georeference it. Should take less than 5 minutes.  If you don't know how .... follow this link:  http://www.gistrainingsource.com/Resources/Georeferencing.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the georeferencing toolbar tools to georeference the image.